# How to use Python console under QGIS 2 with gdal module?

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, plugins

I am trying to move my plugin from QGIS 1.8 to QGIS2.0. However, the gdal module cannot use under QGIS2.0.
I try to use Python console, typing:

```
    import gdal  #it's OK
    gdal.GetDriverByName( 'GTiff' ) # dosen't work, got an AttributeError
```

But the 'smart spelling' give 'GetDriverByName' attribute.(and has 'two'?! one for method and another one for attribute?? )
I also typing:

```
    dir(gdal)
```

But No these methods or attributes found

What can I do??  Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use:

```
import osgeo.gdal
osgeo.gdal.GetDriverByName
```

Doing `import gdal` returns the gdal module in the processing toolbox.

Comment: Thanks, I use import osgeo.gdal as gdal in my script, then it works.